# How to update AppSync with User Pools in a NodeJS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-appsync

I'm trying to perform an update on my AWS DynamoDB table with the aws-sdk. The table was set up with an AWS Amplify schema.graphql file and has an `owner` field.

I currently have AppSync working when set up with IAM:

```js
import {
  AUTH_TYPE,
  AWSAppSyncClientOptions,
  AWSAppSyncClient,
} from "aws-appsync";
import { config, Credentials } from "aws-sdk";

const credentials = config.credentials as Credentials;

// GraphQL client config
const appSyncClientConfig: AWSAppSyncClientOptions = {
  url: APPSYNC_URL, // from AppSync console.
  region: "eu-west-2",
  auth: {
    type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM as const,
    credentials: credentials as Credentials,
  },
  offlineConfig: {
    keyPrefix: "public",
  },
  disableOffline: true,
};

const appSyncClient = new AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncClientConfig); // Initialise the AppSync client
```

So in order to adapt it to use Cognito User Pools, it looks like the `auth` prop in the above should be updated to:

```js
    auth: {
      type: AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS as const,
      jwtToken: jwtToken,
    },
```

I have tried generating the jwtToken on the client side and passing that to the Lambda:

```js
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
...
const session = await Auth.currentSession();
const jwtToken = session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(); // pass this to Lambda
```

This results in the following error in my Lambda:

```json
errors": [
                {
                    "errorType": "UnauthorizedException",
                    "message": "Valid authorization header not provided."
                }
            ],
...
    "message": "Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 401"
```

I've also tried to use `initiateAuth()`, which is referenced in the [AWS-SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#initiateAuth-property) (which are referenced in the [cognito-user-identity-pools APIReference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html#API_InitiateAuth_SeeAlso)), but I can't figure it out yet.

I found an example somewhere on StackOverflow/Github:

```js
// structured params for the adminInitiateAuth method
const initiateAuthParamsOriginal: aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AdminInitiateAuthRequest =
  {
    UserPoolId: YOUR_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID, // eg "eu-west-2_<9 random digits>" event.identity.claims.iss
    ClientId: YOUR_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID, // eg "<26 random digits>" in event.identity.claims.client_id
    AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH", // What is this?
    AuthParameters: {
      USERNAME: YOUR_ADMIN_USER_USERNAME, // Believe this is event.identity.claims.username
      PASSWORD: YOUR_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD, // What is this?
    },
  };
// Get an Id Token (JWT) for the user
function getCredentialsOriginal() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cognitoSP.adminInitiateAuth(initiateAuthParams, (authErr, authData) => {
      if (authErr) {
        console.log(authErr);
        reject(authErr);
      } else if (authData === null) {
        reject("Auth data is null");
      } else {
        console.log("Auth Successful");
        resolve(authData);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

But I can't get anything to work so far?

Comment: Have you checked fantastic Nader Dabit tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/?

Comment: Thanks, this only shows IAM and API methods. I'm looking to use Cognito User Pools